# how to stop time delay function

Tags: arduino

I want to stop time delay function when ultrasonic sensor value is < 5cm.
I cant use interrupt for this because ultrasonic sensor send digital signal.
Here my code. here time delay function is,
                           forward();
                           delay(4000);
Actually I want to stop this forward function if sonar reading is <5cm before 4000ms

Any one have a idea what I have to do?

```
void loop {
    if(angleDegrees -10 <headingDegrees && angleDegrees +10 >headingDegrees  ) {
        forward();
        delay(4000);
    }
    if(safeZone>cm) {
        Stop();
    }
    else {
        search();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some things that do not make sense in your post: (" I cant use interrupt for this because ultrasonic sensor send digital signal" - interrupts can only be issued on digital signals, not analog [w/o additional circuitry]). Once `delay(4000);` command is reached it cannot be stopped. What you need to do is check your sonar reading beforehand, and not run the `delay(4000);` command.  Or do a loop with shorter delay commands: `while (sonarCheck(...)) { delay(100); }` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example run a loop 40 times, checking the ultrasonic sensor reading every time.
For example:

```
void loop {
if(angleDegrees -10 <headingDegrees && angleDegrees +10 >headingDegrees  ) {
    forward();
    for(int times=0; times<40; times++) //runs 40 times
    { 
        search(); //Check the sensor
        if(cm<safeZone)
        {
            Stop();
            break; //This exits the for loop
        }
        delay(100); //Waits for 100 ms
    }
}
```